# merge Objects and get JsonObject in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying concatenate two Objects to each other, When you examine to My Code you can see **first_obj** and **gonderici_obj** and I want to get like below JSON code my code is

**My Code**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
let student = JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(student.length);
var gonderi = {
    "GONDERICI": []
};

var obj;

for (var i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
    //console.log("Adı:"+student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_ADI);  

    var first_obj = {
        "HIZMET_SAGLAYICI_ID": student[i].HİZMET_SAĞLAYICI_ID,
        "KARGO_DURUMU": student[i].KARGO_DURUMU,
        "BARKOD_NO": student[i].BARKOD_NO,
        "GONDERİ_TURU": student[i].GONDERİ_TÜRÜ,
        "GONDERI_AGIRLIGI": student[i].GÖNDERİ_AĞIRLIĞI,
        "GONDERİ_YONTEMI": student[i].GÖNDERİ_YÖNTEMİ,
        "GONDERICI_TIPI": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_TİPİ,
        "INTERNET_ALIS_VERISI": student[i].İNTERNET_ALIŞVERİŞİ,
        "YURTDISI_GONDERI": student[i].YURTDIŞI_GÖNDERİ,
        "GUMRUGE_TABI_GONDERI": student[i].GÜMRÜĞE_TABİ_GÖNDERİ,
        "GONDERICI_TIPI": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_TİPİ,
        "GONDERI_TARIHI": student[i].GÖNDERİ_TARİHİ,
        "TESLIM_TARIHI": student[i].TESLİM_TARİHİ


    }

    //console.log(first_obj);

    var gonderici_obj = {
        "ADI": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_ADI,
        "SOYADI": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_SOYADI,
        "TC_KIMLIK_NO": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_TC_KİMLİK_NO,
        "PASAPORT_NO": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_PASAPORT_NO,
        "UNVAN": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_UNVAN,
        "CINSIYETI": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_CINSIYETI,
        "UYRUK": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_UYRUK,
        "ULKE": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_ÜLKE,
        "IL'": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_IL,
        "ILCE": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_ILCE,
        "ADRES": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_ADRES,
        "ADRES_KODU": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_ADRES_KODU,
        "POSTA_KODU": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_POSTA_KODU,
        "IRTIBAT_TEL_1": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_IRTIBAT_TEL_1,
        "IRTIBAT_TEL_2": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_IRTIBAT_TEL_2,
        "E-MAIL": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_E_MAIL,
        "MESLEK": student[i].GÖNDERİCİ_MESLEK

    }

    gonderi.GONDERICI.push(gonderici_obj);
    obj = JSON.stringify(first_obj) + JSON.stringify(gonderi);
    obj = obj.replace(/\}\{/, ",");
    obj = JSON.parse(obj);
}

console.log(obj);
```

**JSON code**

```
{
    "HIZMET_SAGLAYICI_ID ": "973",
    "KARGO_DURUMU ": "TESLİM EDİLDİ",
    "BARKOD_NO": "KP12345678910",
    "GONDERI_TURU": "APS KURYE",
    "GONDERI_AGIRLIGI": "920",
    "GONDERI_YONTEMI": "KARAYOLU",
    "INTERNET_ALIS_VERISI": "E",
    "YURTDISI_GONDERI": "H",
    "GUMRUGE_TABI_GONDERI": "H",
    "GONDERICI_TIPI": "G",
    "GONDERI_TARIHI": "20170310104200",
    "TESLIM_TARIHI": "20170315175030",
    "GONDERICI": [{
        "ADI": "ÇİĞDEM",
        "SOYADI": "DURAN",
        "TC_KIMLIK_NO": "12345678910",
        "PASAPORT NO": "",
        "UNVAN": "BİLGİ TEKNOLOJİLERİ İLETİŞİM KURUMU",
        "CINSIYETI": "K",
        "UYRUK": "TUR",
        "ULKE": "TUR",
        "IL": "ANKARA",
        "ILCE": "YENİMAHALLE",
        "ADRES": "MENEMENCİLER AKARYAKIT TURGUT ÖZAL MAH. 25 SK. 34/5",
        "ADRES_KODU": "",
        "POSTA_KODU": "34500",
        "IRTIBAT_TEL_1": "",
        "IRTIBAT_TEL_2": "",
        "E_MAIL": "cigdem@gmail.com",
        "MESLEK": "MÜHENDİS"
    }]
}
```

Comment: how data structured in data.json?

Answer (score 0):

Well..

I think you should create a `JSONObject` and then you should itinerate this object putting the values from the student array.

You are creating all the time a variable inside the array that you have. It doesn't make sense if you itinerate an array meanwhile you are declaring a variable for every register.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = Object.assign(first_obj, gonderi);
```

Simple use Object.assign function from merge two objects.